# Comparison a number to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

Accidently, I found that I can compare an array as if it's a number in javascript.

```
[3] > 4
false
[3] < 4
true
[3] > [4]
false
[3] < [4]
true
[] > 0
false
[] < 0
false
[] == 0
true
[] === 0
false
[] < 3
true
['3'] == 3
true
['3'] < 3
false
['3'] < 4
true
[3, 4] > [3.5, 2.5]
false
[3, 4] > [2.5, 2.5]
true
```

Is it okay to use this concept? Then which specification section is it from?

(I tested it in the chrome console.)

Comment: Is it okay? Yes, in that it isn't a syntax error and it does follow certain rules. But I can't think of a scenario where it would be sensible to do so. Note also what happens if the array is empty or contains more than one element, or if the element isn't a number...

Comment: Why would you use it?

Comment: Recently an interface has been changed from a number into an array. For compatibility, I would let them both allowed, but I'm afraid of any browser might not behave in the same way.

Comment: @hotohoto But its just an interface, your underline code logic doesn't need to change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Implicit coercion](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md) of JavaScript is at work in this case. For example, in the example of `a < b` where a and b are of different types, 'Abstract Relational Comparison' algorithm '...first calls ToPrimitive coercion on both values, and if the return result of either call is not a string, then both values are coerced to number values using the ToNumber operation rules, and compared numerically.'